# MVC 5 OWIN authentication - how do I prevent registration unless user is already set up within application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an MVC 5 application which uses individual accounts for authentication. I like the option to use google accounts, but I would like to control the setting up of users from within the application. So effectively prevent new registrations . .

My thought is to allow CRUD operations on the ApplicationUsers (ASPNetUsers) table via an admin screen. Any thoughts about how to achieve this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. I have added a field

```
  public bool Active {get;set;}
```

to Application user.

I use CRUD to update the field. I created the CRUD using the automatic scripting in MVC5

Then, in AccountControler\Login

After I get the application user i check the following

```
   var user = UserManager.FindByName(model.Email);

    if (user!=null)
    {
        if (!user.Active)
        {
           ViewBag.Message = "Your account needs to be activated by a human after due diligence. Please wait for account activation.";
           ViewBag.Title = "Account Not Activated";
           return View("Error");
         }
    }
```

I use the Edit Method in Application User to update the Active field.

Also, after I update the field, I send an email to the user that I have done so.

I hope that helps.